# PHP and SetInterval Check Value for Change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to display a 'live data feed' on my website using PHP and JavaScript. In order to achieve this I am querying a MySQL database and retrieving results.

The database table is called `transactions` and is setup as follows;

```
+---------------------+--------+----------+
| TimeStamp           | CardNo | SerialNo |
+---------------------+--------+----------+
| 2017-08-04 15:28:29 | 883662 | 544331   |
+---------------------+--------+----------+
| 2017-08-03 19:44:19 | 100927 | 544332   |
+---------------------+--------+----------+
| 2017-08-0311:21:24  | 655210 | 544333   |
+---------------------+--------+----------+
```

The `SerialNo` column acts as a primary key and is incremented on each table insert.

The PHP script that queries the table is called `getData.php`, the contents are as follows;

**getData.php**

```
$query = "SELECT TimeStamp, CardNo, SerialNo FROM transactions ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 1";
if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

I have some javascript that calls this script every 2 seconds, the `index.html` is as follows;

**index.html**

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval("showData()", 2000);
    });

    function showData() {
        $.getJSON("getData.php", null, function(data) {
            if (data != null) {
                $("#data").prepend($("<div>"+data.TimeStamp + " " + data.CardNo+"</div>").fadeIn("slow"));
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div id="data"></div>
```

I can successfully display the live feed on the html page and it does refresh every 2 seconds as expected, however the feed will display the same record every 2 seconds until there's a new insert in the database - see pic;

[image]

I only want to display the **new records once**, i.e Only display a record when the `SerialNo` has incremented.

Presumably I need to check if the `data.SerialNo` has incremented, otherwise don't display anything?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `$.getJSON("getData.php?lastSerialNo=something", ...` ???

Comment: I mean, talk it out to yourself what you want.  I want the records after my last serial number.  But to do that I need the last serial number for the query.  So I have to send that on the request.  Now I have to use that in the query.  How do I do that?  Well I ....

Comment: Step one.  If you want to only get the records after a certain criteria on your backend, you have to send those criteria values to the backend.  So your request will have to change to send them, like my first comment said.  It will pass 'lastSerialNo' to the backend with a value of 'something'.  Change that to make something be your last serial number.  Go from there.

Comment: Another approach should be to persists previous results each time you call your script and use this data to send to your script... as Taplar said... I mean, save the first TimeStamp your get, then transmit this timestamp to your php script and update your request in order to ignore this timestamp of the result... Not sure to be clear enough...

Comment: Send the last id in your ajax request, then  "SELECT ... WHERE SerialNo > " . $_GET['id'].

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestions. I think the part I'm stuck at is how to send the last id in my ajax request. Plus, I still have the same issue of the data feed displaying the same record repeatedly until a new insert is recognised. I only want the data feed to display single unique records. If you could draft a sample answer @Taplar that would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks @EmmanuelDelay that's now the part i'm struggling with.